# RobotLocalization: navsatnode give wrong results with "nan covariance"

Tags: ros, navsat-transform-node, navsat-transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
<node pkg="nostop_robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="test_navsat_node" respawn="true">

  <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="2.38"/>
  <param name="yaw_offset" value="0"/>
  <param name="delay" value="0"/>
  <param name="map_frame" value="SRworld"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
   <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
   <param name="world_frame" value="SRworld"/>
   <!--  Placeholder for input topic remapping-->
   <!--remap from="don't touch" to="my_topic" /-->
  <remap from="/imu/data" to="/test_imu" />
  <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/test_gps" />
  <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/output_of_ekf1" />
  
   <!-- Placeholders for output remapping. -->
  <remap from="/odometry/gps" to="/odometry_from_gps"/>
  <remap from="/gps/filtered" to="/gps_filtered"/>
  
</node>
```

This code returns a nan covariance and the transform doesn't work.
Imu data, gps data and odometry data are ok. Frames are correctly choose, then where is the problem?

Bag file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_1fqLQnQO6obUg0Y3BfekZOdTQ
Message screenshot : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_1fqLQnQO6oWjM3WnpFTW9TM2s

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223697/robotlocalization:-navsatnode-give-wrong-results-with-%22nan-covariance%22/) by [Niko](https://answers.ros.org/users/25510/niko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-01-15**:
Also, is this from source, or is this the installed binary?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-01-15**:
Also, I lack permission to view the bag file. It would be really helpful if you could also paste sample messages from all of your input sources in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the answer but I have resolved. The problem was in the imu frame_id = ' ' instead frame_id = base_link. Beginner mistake!

---

Originally posted by [Niko](https://answers.ros.org/users/25510/niko/) with karma: 33 on 2016-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-03-08**:
Glad you found a solution!